# Как правильно очищать память у массива обьектов содержащего другие массивы обьектов? - си

Tags: c

К примеру у меня есть:

```
struct A {
    int size;
    int * array_int;
};

struct B {
    int size;
    struct A * array_A;
};

struct B * main_array;
```

где `struct A * array_A`, `struct B * main_array` и `int * array_int` массивы с динамически выделенной памятью.

Что требуется сделать чтобы очистить память от массива `struct B * main_array`? Следует в начале очистить память для всех под-обьектов или же можно просто очистить память для внешнего массива?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Программа будет яснее и короче, если будете рекурсивно всё удалять. А это значит, сначала сыновья.

```
for( x из main_array )
  DestructorB( x );
free(main_array);

void DestructorB(struct B * const b) {
  for(size_t i = 0 ;i<b->size;++i)
    DestructorA(b->array_A+i);
  free(b->array_A); }

void DestructorA(struct A * const a) {
  free(a->array_int); }
```

Comment: то есть все нужно очищать по очереди, ладно, спасибо

Comment: Если вы удалите `main_array`, то как доберётесь до этих структур, чтобы удалить?

Comment: действительно..

Comment: почему вы тут используете const? а не просто указатель?

Comment: Привычка, это аналог плюсовой ссылки.